# How to write a SQL Server 2008 query based on parameter passed at run time

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have 4 parameters that are being passed to the query. My requirement is to return result even though any of them are null. Do we have to write a if condition in the where clause or write a dynamic query? The parameter has a `datetime` being one of them and also `datetime` being a range variable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us what your basic SQL query looks like??

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you need to prepare a where clause which handles a NULL parameter value too.

So, this could be a solution:

```
declare @myDate datetime = NULL;
declare @myRangeFrom datetime = NULL;
declare @myRangeUntil datetime = NULL;

SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE (@myDate IS NULL OR tblDate = @myDate)
AND (@myRangeFrom IS NULL OR tbl2ndDate >= @myRangeFrom)
AND (@myRangeUntil IS NULL OR tbl2ndDate <= @myRangeUntil)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking for is "SQL Optional Parameters":

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestProc
(
    @Param1 varchar(50) = NULL,
    @Param2 varchar(50) = NULL,
    @Param3 varchar(50) = NULL
)
AS
SELECT
    *
FROM
    TestTable

WHERE
    ((@Param1 IS NULL) OR (col1 = @Param1)) AND 
    ((@Param2 IS NULL) OR (col2 = @Param2)) AND 
    ((@Param3 IS NULL) OR (col3 = @Param3))
```

However there is a performance problem with this query; as elegant as it looks, it will prevent SQL Server from correctly using your indexes.  If performance is a problem you're better off using sp_executesql to dynamically create a string and execute it as a query.

See:  http://www.davewentzel.com/content/optional-sql-parameters-and-performance

Comment: HI Thanks for the reply but what if datetime has to be defined with between.I mean 
create procedure [spDate]
( @StartDate datetime=null, @EndDate datetime=null)
as


SELECT Title, TargetDate
FROM  Projects
WHERE  (TargetDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)
        
GO

Even though I handle NUll but the problem would be it gets the result of all the records after the passed date to the parameter.For Ex:if I pass 12/31/11 the result shoud be record having 12/31/11 but the result now shows all after 12/31/11 including the mentioned date